# Append to line with a specific key in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file test.txt which has a line like below

```
values =  abc, def, dfg, ert, sdf, sfd, sdf
```

I use the shell script to add a new value with comma separation in the values in the test,txt.

For example, I need to **add** the 'ghf' in the test.txt:

```
values =  abc, def, dfg, ert, sdf, sfd, sdf, ghf
```

Also I need to remove the value.

For example, if I need to **remove** the 'ert' in the test.txt:

```
values =  abc, def, dfg, sdf, sfd, sdf, ghf
```

How can I achieve this in shell script?

**EDITED :**

If I give the

```
echo "abc" >> test.txt
```

It is able to append the abc to the end of the file but I need to append to the values= field in test.txt

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: @Cyrus I have edited please check this

Comment: @JNevil I have edited please check this

Answer (score 0):

There a several ways to accomplish this, but here are two simple sed commands that should get you started.  First, to append the string ", grt" to the end of the line beginning with "values = " in the file test.txt:

```
sed -e "s/\(values = .*$\)/\1, ghf/" < test.txt
```

Second, to remove the string ", grt" from the line beginning with "values = " in the same file:

```
sed -e "s/\(values = .*\), grt\(.*$\)/\1\2/" < test.txt
```

These are just examples -- for example, the second command will fail if the string "grt" is the first string after the equals sign -- but hopefully they will get you started.